# convert keras.engine.Layer to tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, layer

Hi everyone i want to convert custom layer written with keras to tensorflow.

I know how i can write custom layer keras, this is keras site's example:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import numpy as np

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
       self.output_dim = output_dim
       super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(input_shape[1],   
                                  self.output_dim),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, x):
       return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
       return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

I want know if should I build my tensorflow custom layer with a class?
and also if it is possible with a example.

Answer (score 0):

If there is someone with same problem I have used tf.layers.Layer with same body.